# How does reparametrization change the shape of a curve?

Tags: general-topology

This is a question about the reparametrization of a curve.

Say $\psi:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is a continuous mapping where $\psi(0)=0$ and $\psi(1)=1$. Also, $f:[0,1]\to X$ is a continuous mapping; a continuous curve.

Is the curve $f$ (which can be interpreted both as a mapping and a curve) different in any way as compared to $f\circ \psi$?

I don't see how the shapes of the curves can be different, except if $[0,1]$ is graphed on the x-axis and $f$ or $(f\circ \psi)$ on the Y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

The maps $f$ and $f\circ\psi$ have the same image because $\psi$ is surjective (a consequence of the intermediate value theorem) and so the 'shape' of the curve will not change. A reparameterisation is specifically the way that a point will move along such a curve. i.e how is the curve drawn out as the value of $t$ in $[0,1]$ changes from $0$ to $1$ - in particular the speed and/or direction.

Comment: Thank you. This confirms my intuition.

Answer (score 0):

If $\psi$ is not monotonic, it will double back on itself as it traces out the curve defined by $f$. Whether this is significant depends on what you are doing $-$ if you are trying to measure the length of the curve, for instance, it will certainly be significant.

Comment: Although if you're careful enough with signs to properly record when you're tracing the curve backwards, you'll still get the length correct.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I don't think that can be made to work.

Comment: Here's a simple example. Consider the path from $-1$ to $1$ on the real line. You compute its length with $\int_{-1}^{1} \, dx $. Now you can reparametrize this by $x = \sin(\theta)$, $\theta \in [-\pi/2, 5\pi/2]$, which doubles back on itself, and you'll find that $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{5\pi/2} \cos \theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta$$ still gives the correct value of $2$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: But curve length is much more complicated than simply subtracting the $x$-coordinates of the end-points! You have to integrate $\sqrt{\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}^2 + \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}^2}$. Do you want to take the negative square root over certain portions of the curve? If so, what is your criterion? In general, this is insoluble, I think.

Comment: Would it not be enough to just pick a finite set of subintervals in $[0,1]$ on which the resulting map is bijective (except 2 to 1 on endpoints)? Under fairly general smoothness conditions I think such a set of subintervals should always exist.

Comment: @Daniel: Perhaps. But it's definitely simpler to require that $\psi$ be monotonic.

Comment: @Tony: If your parametrization has the same orientation as the curve at a given value of the parameters, you take the positive square root. Otherwise you take the negative square root. (note that my example has this feature: I take $|\cos \theta|$ when it's tracing the interval forwards, and $-|\cos \theta|$ when it's tracing the interval backwards)